# using *ngIf in angularMaterialTable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to use `*ngIf` to change show format data in angular material column.

I write this code:

```html
<span *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="item.vlaue">
        <span></span>
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ 'POST_LIKE.POST_TITLE'| translate }} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="item.value === dateTimeOffset">
                <span *ngIf="lang=='fa'">{{ element[item.vlaue] | jalali }}</span>
                <span *ngIf="lang!='fa'"> {{element[item.vlaue] | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}} </span>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="item.value === string">
                {{element[item.vlaue]}}
            </span>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</span>
```

and this is my list :

```js
this.items= [
    { header: 'x', vlaue: 'createdUserFullName', type: 'string' },
    { header: 'y', vlaue: 'postTitle', type: 'string' },
    { header: 'y', vlaue: 'createdOnUtc', type: 'dateTimeOffset' }
]
```

I need when when `item.value === dateTimeOffset` show data by this format :

```html
<span *ngIf="item.value === dateTimeOffset">
    <span *ngIf="lang=='fa'">{{ element[item.vlaue] | jalali }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="lang!='fa'"> {{element[item.vlaue] | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}}</span>
</span>
```

but it does not work and show it by defualt format :

```html
<span *ngIf="item.value === string">
    {{element[item.vlaue]}}
</span>
```

Whats the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: what is dateTimeOffset, is it a property or just a string literal , if it is a literal then should be single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dateTimeOffset  should be in single quote if that is a string. Try with this, It should work.

```
*ngIf="item.value === 'dateTimeOffset'"
```

Or

```
<span *ngIf="item.value === 'string'">
    {{element[item.vlaue]}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made some spelling errors, and you're accessing the wrong property, so your condition is never met.

Change your code to the following:

**List**

```
this.items= [
        { header: 'x', value: 'createdUserFullName', type: 'string' },
        { header: 'y', value: 'postTitle', type: 'string' },
        { header: 'y', value: 'createdOnUtc', type: 'dateTimeOffset' }
    ]
```

**Span**

```
<span *ngIf="item.type === 'dateTimeOffset'">
  <span *ngIf="lang=='fa'">{{ element[item.value] | jalali }}</span>
  <span *ngIf="lang!='fa'"> {{element[item.value] | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}}</span>
</span>
```

**Other Span**

```
<span *ngIf="item.type === string">
  {{element[item.value]}}
</span>
```

**Longer Block Of Code**

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="item.value">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ 'POST_LIKE.POST_TITLE'| translate }}/th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <span *ngIf="item.type === 'dateTimeOffset'">
          <span *ngIf="lang=='fa'">{{ element[item.value] | jalali }}</span>
          <span *ngIf="lang!='fa'"> {{element[item.value] | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'}} </span>
         </span>

         <span *ngIf="item.type === string">
           {{element[item.vlaue]}}
         </span>
       </td>
  </ng-container>
</span>
```